# Bugging function with in_array loop

Tags: php, mysql, function

My site is currently bugging a lot (slow loading and missing MySQL data) - I have found a very odd explanation. A single line in one of my functions is the problem.

The function looks like this:

```
function lukkedage($aar) {
$aaret = date("Y", $aar);

$lukkedagearray = array(
date("d-m-Y",easter_date($aaret)),          //Påskedag
date("d-m-Y",easter_date($aaret)-259200),   //Skærtorsdag
date("d-m-Y",easter_date($aaret)-172800),   //Langfredag
date("d-m-Y",easter_date($aaret)+86400),    //2. Påskedag
date("d-m-Y",easter_date($aaret)+2246400),  //Store Bededag
date("d-m-Y",easter_date($aaret)+3369600),  //Kristi himmelfart
date("d-m-Y",easter_date($aaret)+4233600),  //Pinsedag
date("d-m-Y",easter_date($aaret)+4320000),  //2. pinsedag
"24-12-".$aaret,
"25-12-".$aaret,
"26-12-".$aaret,
"27-12-".$aaret,
"28-12-".$aaret,
"29-12-".$aaret,
"30-12-".$aaret,
"31-12-".$aaret,
"01-01-".$aaret
);

return $lukkedagearray;
}


function NaesteArbejdsdag($dato) {
$naeste = date('d-m-Y H:i', strtotime(date("d-m-Y H:i",$dato) .' +1 day'));
$strnaeste = strtotime($naeste);

$ny = $strnaeste;
while(date("l",$ny) == "Sunday" OR date("l",$ny) == "Saturday" 
OR in_array(date("d-m-Y",$strnaeste), lukkedage($strnaeste), true)
){
$ny += 60*60*24;
}

if(date("H",$ny) >= "17" OR date("H",$ny) < "09"){
$ny = strtotime(date("d-m-Y",$ny)."09:00");
}

return date("d-m-Y H:i",$ny);
}
```

The first function is an array that contains all of the holidays, and the next function is where it checks when the next workday will be - if tomorrow is a saturday or sunday or holiday, skip to the next day.

The part that is making me crazy is:

```
OR in_array(date("d-m-Y",$strnaeste), lukkedage($strnaeste), true))
```

Shouldn't that work? I believe that the reason for my problems is an extremely long execution time - but why?

Comment: Can you please explain what that function is supposed to do? It's difficult to understand because of the non English names sorry

Comment: Yeah sure, I'm sorry. The first function is making a list of holidays (easter, christmas and so on) in Denmark, and in the second function, it should find the next work day. It checks if tomorrow is weekend or a holiday, if it is, it skips to the next day. This loops until there is a work day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few problems I see straight away:

1: The `easter_date()` function is missing.

2: You use `$ny` and `$strnaeste` variables in the `while` loop, but you only update `$ny`. Use ONE variable.

```
$ny = $strnaeste;
while(date("l",$ny) == "Sunday" OR 
      date("l",$ny) == "Saturday" OR 
      in_array(date("d-m-Y",$ny), lukkedage($ny), true)) $ny += 60*60*24;
```

Comment: You are absolutely right. The loop was infinite because it checked the start date $strnaeste and not the variable changing date $ny. It works fine now. Just for the record easter_date() is a standard PHP function.

Comment: Yes, I added the corrected code, and then you need to use `lukkedage()` multiple times so I removed that point from my answer.